# How would I find distinct rows based on 2 columns that are tied to multiple values in a third column?

Tags: sql-server

I have a table similar to this, but it contains many duplicates accross all values, similar to the first three rows.

```
 Company  Division   Contracts
-------  --------   ---------
ABC      Avril      0000111
ABC      Avril      0000111
ABC      Avril      0000111
ABC      Blocky     0000247
DEF      Blocky     0000346
GHI      Franklin   0000123
GHI      Franklin   0000156
JKL      Owned      0000458
JKL      Owned      0000567
MNO      Owned      0000672
ABC      Owned      0000672
```

I am looking to narrow down the list to only items rows where the only diffference is the contract number from another row.

```
Example:
Company  Division   Contracts
-------  --------   ---------
GHI      Franklin   0000123
GHI      Franklin   0000156
JKL      Owned      0000458
JKL      Owned      0000567
```

However right now my query returns every Distinct combination of company, division and contract

```
 Company  Division   Contracts
-------  --------   ---------
ABC      Avril      0000111
ABC      Blocky     0000247
DEF      Blocky     0000346
GHI      Franklin   0000123
GHI      Franklin   0000156
JKL      Owned      0000458
JKL      Owned      0000567
MNO      Owned      0000672
ABC      Owned      0000672
```

I believe that my mistake is in the GROUP BY and HAVING arguments

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.company, A.division, A.contracts
FROM inventory A
     Join (SELECT *, Cnt = Dense_Rank() over (Partition By company, division Order By contracts ) From inventory) B on A.company=B.company and A.division=B.division and cnt > 1

GROUP BY A.company, A.division, A.contracts
HAVING count(concat(A.company, A.division)) > 1
  AND count(concat(A.division, A.contracts)) > 1

ORDER BY family
```

Comment: I don't think your join nor `count(concat(A.division, A.contracts)) > 1` is necessary. At a glance, removing these two things should give you the desired results unless i'm missing something

Comment: SELECT * FROM inventory A INNER JOIN inventory B ON A.Company = B.Company AND A.Division = B.Division AND A.Contracts <> B.Contracts

Comment: You are correct in that I can get rid of   'count(concat(A.division, A.contracts)) > 1' .

Comment: @scsimon 22 however, there are stlll singular results appearing in data, possibly due to large number of duplicates across all fields.

Comment: ah yes... select the distinct into a CTE first and then perform the same logic you have here and you should be solid. I wasn't thinking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

rextester: http://rextester.com/RTLSW20510

```
create table #inventory (Company varchar(32), Division varchar(32), Contracts varchar(32));
  insert into #inventory (Company, Division, Contracts) values
     ('ABC','Avril','0000111'),('ABC','Avril','0000111'),('ABC','Avril','0000111')
    ,('ABC','Blocky','0000247'),('DEF','Blocky','0000346'),('GHI','Franklin','0000123')
    ,('GHI','Franklin','0000156'),('JKL','Owned','0000458'),('JKL','Owned','0000567')
    ,('MNO','Owned','0000672'),('ABC','Owned','0000672');
with cte as (
  select 
        a.Company
      , a.Division
      , a.Contracts
      , rn = row_number() over (partition by company, division order by contracts )
    from #inventory as a
    group by a.Company, a.Division, a.Contracts
    /* this could be written using `select distinct` instead of using the `group by ...` */
)
select 
      cte.Company
    , cte.Division
    , cte.Contracts 
  from cte 
  where exists (
    select 1
      from cte as i
      where i.Company  = cte.Company
        and i.Division = cte.Division
        and i.rn>1
        )
```

This can be simplified using `count() over()`

rextester: http://rextester.com/GGR62900

```
with cte as (
  select distinct
        a.Company
      , a.Division
      , a.Contracts
      , rn = row_number() over (partition by a.company, a.division order by a.contracts )
      , CountOver = count(a.contracts) over (partition by a.company, a.division)
    from #inventory as a
    group by a.Company, a.Division, a.Contracts
     -- this could also be written using group by a.Company, a.Division, a.Contracts, [...]
)
/* select from cte can be simplified to using CountOver vs where exists(select ...)*/
select 
      cte.Company
    , cte.Division
    , cte.Contracts 
    -- extra columns
    , cte.rn
    , cte.CountOver
  from cte 
  where cte.CountOver>1
```

Comment: the `group by` handles that in the `cte`. He's looking for multiple contracts from the same company and division.

Comment: how would I add cte to an existing database query?

Comment: You don't need to, it's a `common table expression`. It's another, cleaner way of writing a subquery. Try the rextester link. more about `ctes`: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: I must be doing something wrong because I can't just add the CTE

Comment: Make sure you aren't keeping my temp table's `#` in front of `inventory`.

Comment: SOLVED, The data I am working with is larger than this question, so in trying to make it simpler I had abstracted away some filtering in a WHERE clause. However, that filtering in the clause was outside of the JOIN clause. This was causing rows to be filtered after the table creation.

Comment: Question to you. I would love to give you the attributions for helping me, but should I not delete this question, because the solution was different than the questions original problem?

Comment: You can edit your question to clarify, if you want. It was clear enough to me.

Comment: Good answer Zim but you could combine it to remove the CTE and speed it up

Answer (score 0):

You could also just use the `DISTINCT` in your `CONCAT` portion of your `HAVING` clause. This eliminates the use of the `CTE` and should increase performance.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    A.company, 
    A.division, 
    A.contracts
FROM inventory A
GROUP BY A.company, A.division, A.contracts
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT CONCAT(A.company, A.division)) > 1
ORDER BY A.family
```

Comment: This doesn't work because you're grouping by `a.contracts` in this query so the `count(distinct concat(a.company, a.division)` always = 1. rextester: http://rextester.com/GGR62900 But this did prompt me to post an alternate answer using `count() over()` from the cte. Thanks!